# Transcendence of Liouville-Like Numbers

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

[Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) such as
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{10^{k!}}$$
are known to be transcendental, essentially from Diophantine approximation type arguments. Using stronger results than what Louiville had immediate access to (like [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem)), I think we can show numbers such as
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{10^{3^k}}$$
are transcendental as well, but I don't know how to do better than this.

As an actual question, is it known if
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{10^{k^2}}$$
is transcendental? What is the state of the art here?

Comment: Regarding "I think we can show numbers such as", see [*An "oceans of zeros" proof that a certain non-Liouville number is transcendental*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324154) by Melvin John Knight (1991) and [*The many faces of the Kempner number*](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Adamczewski/adam6.html) by Boris Adamczewski (2013).

Comment: The final series you ask about is known to be transcendental, though proving that seems to require a deep result of Nesterenko on values of modular functions. See the [answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to).